# evaluate residue at z=1 $ \frac{e^{z^2}}{z^5(1-z^2)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate the residue at $z=1$ $$ f(z) =  \frac{e^{z^2}}{z^5(1-z^2)} $$

when I use the limit method for $z=1$, $ \lim \frac{e^{z^2}(1-z)}{z^5(1+z)(1-z)}$ gives $\frac{e}{2}$ which is wrong

when I use other methods it turns out to be $-\frac{e}{2}$ what did I do wrong with the limit?

Answer (score 2):

You have to evaluate
$$
\lim_{z\to1}(z-1)\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^5(1-z^2)},
$$
not
$$
\lim_{z\to1}(1-z)\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^5(1-z^2)}.
$$